# fxri console window closes as soon as it opens... cannot execute fxri in Windows Ruby 2.0 environment

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, ruby-2.0

I have installed Ruby 2.0 from

file:  rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p0.exe

site:  http://files.rubyforge.vm.bytemark.co.uk/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p0.exe

I cannot get **fxri** to execute from the cmd prompt, within irb, within a ruby window, or by clicking on the icon within my OS explorer window. I've tried to execute **fxri** in these four ways by referencing the multiple fxri files throughout the Ruby folders.. the primary one being (C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\fxri-0.3.7\fxri.rb)

I did the command **load gem fxri**, and a console popped up saying that it was loading the gem, then it gave me a message saying that it was successfully loaded.

I've tried typing out the full path name in the cmd prompt, irb window, and ruby window,

AND

I've tried to launch it by typing **fxri** after going into the environment variables settings on my OS (Vista 32 bit) and setting **fxri** to reference (C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\fxri-0.3.7\fxri.rb).

None of this has worked.

I've looked inside the fxri.rb file and could not find any reference to **rubyw** that I could change to **ruby** to make it windowed instead of windowless.

I have searched for hours for references to fxri incompatibilities in a 2.0 environment and found none.

Any insight and/or fixes would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the fx gem is compiled against a different version of ruby?  Typically you should be able to add c:\ruby200\bin to your path then run "fxri" from a console...